# ValueError at /register/ Users must have an email address

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-custom-user

This is my code in views.py

```
if form.is_valid():
        print(form.cleaned_data)
        username  = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
        email  = form.cleaned_data.get("email")
        password  = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
        new_user  = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
```

Here is what is printed from the line `'print(form.cleaned_data)'`

```
{'full_name': 'Ross', 'email': 'tree34-5@hotmail.com', 'profilepicture': None, 'password1': 'tree', 'password2': 'tree'}
```

Here is my code from models.py

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, full_name=None, password=None, is_active=True, is_staff=False, is_admin=False):
        print(email)
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Users must have an email address")
```

`'print(email)'` returns `None`. I don't understand why `'print(email)'` is not returning tree34-5@hotmail.com. I keep getting the error message "Users must have an email address".

[image]

Comment: The first argument you're passing to `create_user` is `username`, which doesn't exist in your form data.

Comment: In other words, try `new_user  = User.objects.create_user(email, password)`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this:

```
def create_user(self, email, full_name=None, password=None, is_active=True, is_staff=False, is_admin=False):
```

the first parameter you pass in should be email. But based on your code:

```
new_user  = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
```

you are passing in a "username" instead of an email. That's the major problem.

You might consider to use "form.save()" instead of calling a method.

Answer (score 0):

Your form.cleaned_data does not contain a username field hence None is returned with

```
form.cleaned_data.get("username")
```

You then set your email field to the username value as you have e-mail as a positional argument and passed in username as the first argument in this line

```
new_user  = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
```

Change that line to the one below, this should get you what you want. It will unpack the dictionary into the arguments in the function automatically.

```
new_user  = User.objects.create_user(**form.cleaned_data)
```

Answer (score -1):

Adding to Wind's answer: if you insist on using `User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)`, you must change your create_user to this:

```py
def create_user(self, full_name=None, email, password=None, ...):
```

The reason why is that Django's `create_user` does not provide keyword arguments and therefore you must place everything in order. You need to **swap the arguments "username" and "email" instead of simply replacing** it otherwise the "password" parameter wouldn't work also.

[Reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_user)